# adding hyperlink to video in opencv

Tags: opencv, text, hyperlink, overlay

I know, it is possible to add text in video and overlay images in OpenCV. Can we make hyperlink to the text and overplayed images, when a user click, we redirect him/her to a website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I assume that you try to use internal GUI features of OpenCV's HighGUI module.

[Here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html) you can find a number of mouse event callbacks for the opencv-highgui windows, which can be used to determine a position of the click and do what's necessary (start a browser, etc). There's no simplified hyperlink functionality in OpenCV's highgui windows.